# Fortran to C# conversion

Tags: c#, razor, fortran77

I have a code in fortran where I used to the following subroutine

```
    subroutine bit_mask(inum)
    integer*2 inum
integer*2 iclass,ident,length
common/header/ iclass,ident,length

iclass = iand(inum,'F000'X)
iclass = ishft(iclass, -12)
ident  = iand(inum,'0FE0'X)
ident  = ishft(ident,  -5 )
length = iand(inum,'001F'X)
c       write(*,*) 'Class/Identifier/Length =',iclass,ident,length
return
end
```

Now I like to convert it in C#. 
Please help me. what is iand equvalent in c# and ishft equivalent to C#

Answer (score 2):

`iand` would be equivalent to the [bitwise and operator `&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)

`ishift` with a second parameter less than 0 would be equivalent to the [right-shift operator `>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx)

```
iclass = inum & 0xf000;
iclass = iclass >> 12;
ident = inum & 0xfe0;
ident = ident >> 5;
length = inum & 0x1f;
```

It looks like the code is extracting integer fields from a two byte integer:

```
4 bits = iclass
7 bits = ident
9 bits = inum

0xf000 == 0y1111 0000 0000 0000
0x0fe0 == 0y0000 1111 1110 0000
0x001f == 0y0000 0000 0001 1111
```

After and'ing the value out, it gets shifted to the correct position:

```
       0xa024 == 0y1010 0000 0010 0100
&      0xf000 == 0y1111 0000 0000 0000
--------------------------------------
       0xa000 == 0y1010 0000 0000 0000
>> 12
--------------------------------------
       0x000a == 0y0000 0000 0000 1010
```